# Left bit rotation of a string Objective C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I've been given the following `C++` function to do a left bit rotation of a string, I need to implement it in `Objective C`(Obviously I've added the logging bit at the bottom):

```
void left_rotate ( uint16_t *in,
              uint16_t *out,
              int16_t   len,
              int16_t   shift )
{
    int16_t i, j;

    j = (len / 2) - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < (len / 2); i++) {
        out[i] = (uint16_t) (in[i] << shift);
        if (i < j) {
            out[i] |= in[i + 1] >> ((int16_t) len - shift);
        } else {
            out[i] |= in[0] >> ((int16_t) len - shift);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"In: %hd", (short)in);
    NSLog(@"Out: %hd", (short)out);

    unsigned char * char1 = out;

    NSLog(@"Char: %s", char1);

    NSData * data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:char1 length:sizeof(char1)];

    NSLog(@"Data: %@", data1);

}
```

However I'm not entirely sure how it's supposed to work. I've tried to call it as follows:

```
NSString * originStringData = @"acf7183f7673200BBA7719775b20393c4487fa008e13542f4013eb9b2eb7490e";

NSString * RotateNumber = @"0003";

NSData *data = originStringData;
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(byteData); i++)
{
    u_int16_t data2 = byteData[i];
    int16_t shift1 = (short)[RotateNumber intValue];

    u_int16_t out1;

    left_rotate(&data2, &out1, sizeof(byteData),shift1);
}
```

However it returns:

```
<60055600><b8077b00><c1001c00><f9011f00>
```

Where as the string I actually want is:

```
67b8c1fbb399005dd3b8cbbad901c9e2243fd004709aa17a009f5cd975ba4875
```

What I need to do is perform a left bit rotation on the origin string by the Rotate Number. I'm willing to give anything a go right now so any help would be appreciated, I'm a bit stuck!

Cheers!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems left_rotate doesn't work as you desire.
You can write you own rotate function like this(it works as what you want):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

char char_to_hex(char ch)
{
    char* table = "0123456789abcdef";
    char* str = strchr(table, tolower(ch));
    if(str == NULL)
        return -1;
    return str - table;
}

NSString* left_rotate(NSString* source, NSUInteger shift)
{
    if(shift >= [source length] * 4)
    {
        shift %= ([source length] * 4);
    }
    NSInteger index = shift / 4;
    NSString* tmp = [source substringFromIndex:index];
    NSString* left = [source substringToIndex:index+1];
    tmp = [tmp stringByAppendingString:left];

    shift %= 4;

    //get the internal pointer;
    const char* data = [tmp cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] init];
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < strlen(data) - 1; i++)
    {
        char ch1 = char_to_hex(data[i]);
        char ch2 = char_to_hex(data[i+1]);
        if(ch1 < 0 || ch2 < 0)
            return nil;
        char ch = ((ch1 << shift) | (ch2 >> (4 - shift))) & 0xF;
        result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%x", ch];
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSString* source = @"acf7183f7673200BBA7719775b20393c4487fa008e13542f4013eb9b2eb7490e";
    NSString* result = left_rotate(source, 3);
    NSLog(@"result:%@", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you pass the wrong types to your function, you want to convert your `NSString*` to an array of `int16` before you pass it, what you're doing however, is simply copying the bytes representing the string.

Simply put, if you copy the byes representing `"1"`, you won't get the equivalent of `1`, you have to add some conversion.

Something along these lines (no error handling, assuming a lot of things from your input, adapt!)

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < originStringData.length; ++i {
    unichar oneChar = [originStringData characterAtIndex:i];
    if (isnumber(oneChar)) {
        byteData[i] = oneChar - '0';
    } else {
        byteData[i] = oneChar - 'a' + 10;
    }
}
```

On top of that you want to allocate some space for your `out` too, you're passing a pointer to a single `int16`, allocate another array of the same size and pass that.